# Warum gilt der Gleichsetzungsnominativ nicht als Objekt?

Tags: grammar-identification

Ich habe hier in einer [Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/72182/54398) auf eine andere Frage geschrieben, dass ein Gleichsetzungsnominativ kein Objekt ist. Das wird so auch auf allen einigermaßen seriösen Webseiten, die sich damit beschäftigen, bestätigt. Ich glaube also nicht, dass ich da Blödsinn verzapft habe. Allerdings kam dann in einem Kommentar die Behauptung, das wäre doch der Fall. Beim Versuch, das zu widerlegen, musste ich aber feststellen, das ich das nicht kann. Mir fällt kein stichfestes Argument ein, dass die Behauptung, ein Gleichsetzungsnominativ könne kein Objekt sein, nachvollziehbar untermauert. Auf allen Webseiten, die den Gelichsetzugnsnominativ zum Thema haben, fehlt eine nachvollziehbare Begründung.

Eigentlich verhält sich ein Gleichsetzungsnominativ ja genau so wie ein Objekt, oder nicht? Warum also darf man ihn nicht "Objekt" nennen?

Das was in den folgenden Sätzen fett markiert ist, ist ein Gleichsetzungsnominativ.

> Der Gleichsetzungsnominativ gilt nicht als **Objekt.**
> Apfelsinen sind **Orangen.**
> Meine Tante heißt **Ilse.**
> Sandra entpuppt sich als **Organisationstalent.**
> Georg erwies sich als **begnadeter Tänzer.**
> Du bleibst **ein Träumer.**

Was spricht dagegen, diese Satzteile als "Nominativobjekte" zu bezeichnen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eine einfache Antwort auf die Frage wäre der Hinweis, dass Objekte in Kasussprachen üblicherweise (häufig liest man: immer, aber das entspricht nicht mehr ganz dem Forschungsstand, wenn ich mich recht erinnere) zwingend einen Kasusmarker aufweisen. So ist es insbesondere auch im Deutschen (siehe etwa Hentschel/Weydt 2021: 348), weswegen sich die Frage nach der Beurteilung des "Gleichsetzungsnominativs" banal durch den Hinweis beantworten ließe, dass einer deutschen Nominalphrase im Nominativ nun einmal die Kasusmarkierung fehlt, und also kein Objekt vorliegen kann.

Solche morphologischen Regeln sind schön, aber wohl nicht besonders instruktiv. Mit Blick auf die genannte Klasse der "Gleichsetzungsnominative" (bzw. Ihre Beispiele dazu) dürfte sich anbieten, diese zunächst etwas genauer anzusehen. Nehmen Sie den Satz

> (1) *Apfelsinen sind Orangen.*

(1) ist, wie Ihre anderen Beispiele auch, ein vollständiger Satz. Wichtig: Das Prädikat in (1) ist nicht *sind*, sondern *sind Orangen.* *Orangen* ergänzt die finite *sein*-Kopula erst zum vollständigen Prädikat (sog. Prädikativgefüge). Das Prädikat in Kopulaausdrücken besteht aus (a) der finiten Form des Kopula- oder kopulaähnlichen Verbs; und (b) einer Art Ergänzung, in der Terminologie der IDS-Grammatik (Zifonun et al. 1997: 1105) nennt man diese Prädikativkomplement, meistens spricht man auch einfach von einem Prädikativ (etwa Helbig/Buscha 2001: 450) oder einem Prädikativum. Kopulaverben selbst fehlt es allein an semantischem Gewicht; sie leisten einen vergleichsweise geringen Beitrag zum Aufbau der Satzbedeutung und "denotieren über die bloße Existenz des Subjekt-Denotats hinaus nur Komponenten wie Veränderung, (gruppenbezogene) Gültigkeit oder Modus der Existenz." (Zifonun et al. 1997: 1106)

Mit Kategorien wie "Prädikatsnomen" oder "Gleichsetzungsnominative" wird versucht, verschiedene Erscheinungsformen von Prädikativkomplementen zu systematisieren (die Begriffsverwendung ist leider sehr uneinheitlich). Das mag seine Berechtigung haben, dabei kann allerdings schnell das große Ganze aus dem Blick geraten: die Einsicht, dass es sich bei all diesen Klassen um verschiedenartige Konstituenten *eines Prädikats* handelt (vgl. auch die weitergehende Kritik bei Zifonun et al. ibid.), ob der Satz nun (1) lautet oder (2) *Apfelsinen sind Früchte* oder (3) *Apfelsinen sind teuer*, usw. usf.

Ein Objekt, das mit Dik (1997) und anderen als Gegenpol zum Subjekt in Bezug auf den Sachverhalt im Prädikat gesehen werden kann, setzt seinerseits zwingend die Existenz eines Prädikats voraus, aber dieses Prädikat wird durch die Nominalphrasen in den Beispielen ja eben erst gerade vervollständigt. Erst wenn Sie noch weitere Nominalphrasen ergänzen, können wir zu der Frage kommen, ob es sich dabei dann um Objekte handelt. (Es ist übrigens auch möglich, dass ein Objekt *im Prädikativkomplement* steht: *Sie ist des Wartens müde.* Das nur am Rande.)

---

<sup>Abgekürzte Literatur: Dik, The Theory of Functional Grammar, Part 1 (The Structure of the Clause), 2. Aufl. 1997; Helbig/Buscha, Deutsche Grammatik, 2001; Hentschel/Weydt, Handbuch der deutschen Grammatik, 5. Aufl. 2021; Zifonun et al., Grammatik der deutschen Sprache, Bd. 2, 1997</sup>

Comment: Danke! Das ist eine wirklich fundierte Antwort. Das Argument aus dem 1. Absatz, das man vereinfacht als "wenn es im Nominativ steht kann es kein Objekt sein" formulieren kann, kommt mir sehr willkürlich vor. Und meine Frage war ja eigentlich, warum das nicht sein kann. Aber der Rest der Antwort erklärt es dann: Weil der Gleichsetzungsnominativ ein Teil des Prädikats ist. Bleibt nur die Frage: Wie genau ist der Begriff "Prädikat" definiert?

Answer (score 5):

Man *könnte* im Prinzip den Gleichsetzungsnominativ als "Nominativ-Objekt" bezeichnen (und es gibt durchaus auch [Stellen](https://de-academic.com/dic.nsf/dewiki/1026580), z.B. im Internet, die das tun - seriöse Grammatiken lassen sich i.A. nicht dazu hinreissen). Die Definitionsversuche eines Objekts ("der Teil des Satzes, der der Handlung, die das Verb beschreibt, unterworfen ist", oder "der Teil des Satzes, der eine semantische Funktion trägt, die im Vergleich zum Subjekt die passivere ist") beissen sich leider manchmal mit Passivkonstruktionen und reflexiven Verben, deshalb wird ein Objekt i.A. im Deutschen definiert als "nicht das Subjekt, nicht die Verbform beeinflussende und nicht im Nominativ stehende Nominalkonstruktion, die der Handlung unterworfen ist" - Das beißt sich wiederum mit der Begrifflichkeit "Nominativobjekt", weil "Nominativ" hier als "Nicht-Merkmal" für ein Objekt hergenommen wird. Eben deswegen hat man für diese Konstruktionen den Begriff "Gleichsetzungsnominativ" gefunden.

Comment: "Tim liegt auf dem Bett": Der Teil "auf dem Bett" ist nicht das Subjekt, beeinflusst die Verbform nicht, ist eine Nominalkonstruktion die nicht im Nominativ steht und ist der Handlung unterworfen. Nach deiner Definition wäre dieser Teil daher ein Objekt. Aber [hier](https://www.sofatutor.at/deutsch/videos/adverbiale-bestimmung-oder-praepositionalobjekt-2#praepositionalobjekt-oder-adverbiale-bestimmung) wird genau dieser Satz als Lehrbeispiel dafür verwendet, um zu zeigen, dass "auf dem Bett" kein Objekt ist (sondern eine adverbiale Bestimmung). Wie ist "Objekt" denn wirklich definiert?

Comment: @Alina "Das Bett" ist eben nicht der Handlung unterworfen. Genau das ist der Unterschied zwischen einem Präpositionalobjekt und einer adverbialen Bestimmung. Den Unterschied kann man herausarbeiten, wenn man danach fragt: "Tim liegt wo?" und keine Präposition zur Frage gebraucht wird (Im Gegensatz zu "Tim wartet auf den Bus",  nach dem Bus kann man nicht ohne Präposition fragen, deswegen ist es ein Präpositionalobjekt). Eben weil der Objektbegriff so "wacklig" und schwer zu fassen  ist, versucht man ja "Nominativobjekt" zu vermeiden, um es nicht noch schwieriger zu machen.

Comment: Daher steht in deiner verlinkten alten Antwort auch genau der richtige Satz: "*This can't be an object because it's in nominative case.*" - Eben, weil ein Teil der Definition eines Objekts "kein Nominativ" ist.

Comment: Deutsch wird zu den sog. Akkusativsprachen gerechnet. In diesen Sprachen ist der Großteil der Sätze vom Typ [Agens im Nominativ-intransitives Verb] oder [Agens im Nominativ-transitives Verb-Patiens im Objektkasus]. Sätze mit Gleichsetzungsverben und zwei Nominatvgruppen passen nicht in dieses Schema, was ein Grund ist, sie gesondert zu betrachten. Insbes. gilt der Gleichsetzungsnominativ nicht als Objektkasus, weil dieser Begriff den Sätzen mit transitivem Verb und Patiens vorbehalten ist, wobei Patiens eben der "Teil des Satzes, der der Handlung, die das Verb beschreibt, unterworfen ist" ist.

Comment: @RHa Jetzt hab' ich mir wirklich viel Mühe gegeben, *Patiens* durch einen Ausdruck zu ersetzen, den man auch verstehen kann, und du schleppst ihn wieder an ;)

Answer (score 0):

Aus einem früheren Kommentar von @Janka, da sich keine andere Antwort findet:

Das Prädikativ muss kein Nomen sein, es kann auch ein Adjektiv sein. Und dann stellt sich die Frage, was ein Nomen an dieser Stelle eigentlich von einem Adjektiv unterscheidet. Nichts. Beides sind hier Erweiterungen des Verbs. Adjektive können aber keine Objekte sein. Wolltest du "Nominativobjekte" einführen, müsstest du gleichzeitig einführen, dass das Verb eben ein solches "Nominativobjekt" führen kann, oder aber ein adjektivisches Prädikativ. Und das mit genau derselben Funktion, nämlich als Eigenschaft, die dem Subjekt zugewiesen wird. Sehr kompliziert.

Comment: Es tut mir leid, aber das überzeugt mich nicht.

Comment: @Alina Ich habe nur den vorhandenen Text in ein Antwort umgewandelt. Dadurch, dass es jetzt eine Antwort statt eines Kommentars ist, besteht die Möglichkeit des Abwertens (und Nicht-Akzeptierens).

Comment: Meinst du sowas? *»Meine Tante heißt laut«, »Meine Tante heißt grünlich«?* Oder *»Hans fühlt sich als heroisch«* (statt *»Hans fühlt sich als Held«*)? Es ist zwar richtig, dass bei vielen Verben, bei denen ein Gleichsetzungsnominativ verwendet werden kann, an derselben Stelle auch ein Adjektiv stehen kann (nämlich hier: *»Er ist/bleibt/wird Arzt/krank.« »Er scheint Arzt/krank zu sein.« »Er gilt als Streber/wertvoll.« »Er entpuppt/erweist sich als Streber/wertvoll.«*). Aber bei ...

Comment: ... *»heißen«* und *»sich fühlen als«* geht das nicht. Ich weiß leider auch nicht, was ein Nomen an dieser Stelle eigentlich von einem Adjektiv unterscheidet, aber *»Nichts«* ist sicher falsch. Und deinem Argument, dass ein Verb kein Nominativobjekt führen könne, fehlt auch eine nachvollziehbare Begründung.