# Wie lautet die genaue Definition des Begriffes "Prädikat" in der deutschen Grammatik?

Tags: grammar-identification

Ich habe vor kurzem danach gefragt, warum der Gleichsetzungsnominativ kein Objekt ist, und [die Antwort, die ich für die beste halte,](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/72239/54398) lautet stark verkürzt: Weil ein Gleichsetzungsnominativ ein Teil des Prädikats ist, ein Objekt aber nicht. Das klingt sehr einleuchtend, vor allem wenn man die vollständige Antwort liest, aber daraus ergibt sich eine andere Frage:

- Warum gehören Objekte denn eigentlich nicht zum Prädikat?

In der englischen Grammatik ist ja genau das der Fall: Jedes Wort, das in einem englischen Satz steht, ist entweder Teil des Subjekts oder Teil des Prädikats. Es gibt nur diese beiden Möglichkeiten. Warum gibt es in der deutschen Sprache, die ja mit Englisch so nahe verwandt ist wie sonst kaum eine andere Sprache, in vielen Sätzen noch eine dritte Kategorie, die weder Subjekt noch Prädikat ist? Ist diese dritte Kategorie mit den Objekten identisch? Oder sind Objekte nur ein Teil dessen, was außer Subjekt und Prädikat in einem deutschen Satz vorhanden sein kann?

- Wie genau ist der Begriff "Prädikat" in der deutschen Grammatik definiert?
- Gehört ein Wort, das weder zum Subjekt noch zum Prädikat gehört, immer automatisch zu einem Objekt?

Comment: Ich glaube, ich kann nicht folgen. Zitat von einer Webseite: *Der Satzbau ist im Englischen sehr strikt und folgt grundsätzlich der Regel „Subjekt – Prädikat (Verb) – Objekt“ (SPO).* Was meinst Du dann damit,  dass im Englischen etwas entweder zu Subjekt oder Prädikat gehört (was für mich klingt, als ob es Objekte im Englischen nicht gebe)?

Comment: Welche Instanz sollte denn eine verbindliche Definition geben? Es gibt verschiedene Prädikatsbegriffe. Gewiß nicht vorbildlich, aber immerhin zum Einstieg geeignet ist https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A4dikat_(Grammatik). Dort findet sich auch eine syntaktische Rechtfertigung für unterschiedliche Prädikatsbegriffe im Deutschen und Englischen (aber wenn *Prädikat* sich auf etwas Syntaktisches reduzieren läßt, warum braucht man den Begriff dann überhaupt?). Man wird letztlich damit leben müssen, daß der Begriff unterschiedlich verwendet wird.

Comment: Zitat aus der deutschsprachigen Wikipedia: *Der Begriff Prädikat ist allerdings mehrdeutig, und es sind verschiedene Definitionen im Umlauf.* **Es gibt also keine verbindliche Definition**, und ich persönlich vermeide den Begriff, wenn es um Grammatik geht.

Comment: @guidot: Laut [dieser Website](https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/sentences/what/what-is-a-predicate.html) ist alles, was in einem englischen Satz nicht zum Subjekt gehört, Teil des Prädikats. Die englische [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_(grammar)) sagt: "The first defines a predicate as everything in a standard declarative sentence except the subject, and the other views it as just the main content verb or associated predicative expression of a clause", vergisst dann aber zu erklären, was eine "predicative expression" ist, so dass nur die erste Variante schlüssig ist.

Comment: @DavidVogt: Wenn ich mir die Instanz aussuchen darf, dann nehme ich bitte die, die mal definert hat, dass das Subjekt nicht Teil des Prädikats ist. Das muss ja auch mal irgend eine Instanz zum Faktum erklärt haben. Ich nehme an, diese Instanz war: "die Mehrheit der Germanisten". Wenn das so ist wie ich vermute, dann wünsche ich mir jetzt bitte jene Definition des Begriffs "Prädikat", der die Mehrheit der Germanisten zustimmt.

Answer (score 1):

Objekt und Prädikativum (also u.a. Gleichsetzungsnominativ) sind verschieden, und es ist richtig, dass das Prädikativum ins Prädikat integriert sein kann, aber es muss nicht immer so sein (siehe: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Grammatik#Bestandteile_des_zusammengesetzten_Pr%C3%A4dikats ). Der Unterschied zwischen beiden ist etwas anderes: Das Objekt hat seinen Kasus vom Verb, d.h. das Verb regiert diesen Kasus. Der Gleichsetzungsnominativ ist nicht vom Verb regiert. Dieser Kasus richtet sich stattdessen nach dem Nominativsubjekt (daher der Name: der Kasus wird mit dem Subjektskasus "gleichgesetzt").  Siehe: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A4dikativum#Der_Kasus_von_substantivischen_Pr%C3%A4dikativa (wo es aus der Dudengrammatik zusammengefasst ist).

Deine Fragen zur Definition des Prädikats: Der Wikipedia-Artikel "Prädikat (Grammatik)" ist da sehr ausführlich, allerdings, zum Thema der nichtverbalen Bestandteile so wie Prädikativa steht dort wenig.

Answer (score -1):

Prädikat ist der Kern des Satzes, von dem ergänzende Satzteile (hauptsächlich Subjekt, Objekt, Adverbial) abhängen. Das Prädikat fordert das Objekt. Somit hat das Objekt eine eigene Rolle in der Logik der Satzaufgliederung.
Im Deutschen steht das Subjekt im Nominativ. Per Definition steht das Objekt im Genitiv, Dativ oder Akkusativ. Da der Gleichsetzungsnominativ im Nominativ steht, kann er also kein Objekt sein. Im Englischen gibt es keine Fälle, und deswegen ist das Objekt anders definiert, und es gibt dort keinen Gleichsetzungsnominativ. Er wird stattdessen mit beim Objekt eingeordnet. Du siehst, grammatikalisch unterscheiden sich beide Sprachen sehr.
Anmerkung: Der englische Satz besteht nicht nur aus 2 Bestandteilen, sondern aus Subjekt, Prädikat, Objekt (siehe SPO-Regel) sowie Adverbial.

siehe auch: <sup>[(1)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominativ#Der_Gleichsetzungsnominativ_(Pr%C3%A4dikatsnominativ))</sup><sup>[(2)](https://www.kapiert.de/deutsch/klasse-7-8/sprache-untersuchen/satzglieder/der-gleichsetzungsnominativ/)</sup>

Comment: Was spricht dagegen, dass im Satz "Ich heiße Alina" nur aus dem Wort "heiße" als Prädikat aufzufassen, welches ein Objekt fordert, dass im Nominativ steht? Die Behauptung, dass ein Objekt in jedem beliebigen Fall stehen kann, außer im Nominativ, erscheint mir sehr willkürlich. Da fehlt mir eine nachvollziehbare Begründung. Man könnte ja auch festlegen, dass etwas, das im Dativ steht, per Definition kein Objekt sein kann. Offensichtlich hat man sich dagegen entschieden. Aber warum? Ich erkenne im Ausschluss des Nominativs dieselbe Logik wie im Ausschluss des Dativs, nämlich keine.

Comment: @Alina: Führ dir bitte vor Augen, warum Fälle da sind. Richtig, sie helfen im Satz die Satzglieder ausfindig zu machen. Subjekt steht immer im Nominativ, das direkte Objekt im Akkusativ, das indirekte Objekt im Dativ, das abstammende Objekt im Genitiv. Mit den Fällen hat Deutsch den Vorteil der flexiblen Satzstellung der Satzglieder. Englisch ist mit SPO fixiert, da sie keine Fälle haben. Bei "Ich heiße Alina" können beide Substantive als Subjekt gemeint sein. Sie sind austauschbar. Daher der Gleichsetzungsnominativ. Er spiegelt das Subjekt. Ich verlinke noch in der Antwort auf weitere Seiten.

Comment: Das führt wiederum zurück auf meine Antwort zu deiner Frage nach dem Gleichsetzungsnominativ: Der kann kein Objekt sein, weil "nicht im Nominativ" ein wesentlicher Bestandteil der Objektdefinition ist.

Comment: "Die Behauptung, dass ein Objekt in jedem beliebigen Fall stehen kann, außer im Nominativ, erscheint mir sehr willkürlich". Relativ *ungenau*, aber du muuuustest ja unbedingt danach fragen. Willkür ist etwas anderes.

Answer (score -1):

Aus der vorhergehenden Frage

> **Mir fällt kein stichfestes Argument ein, dass die Behauptung, ein Gleichsetzungsnominativ könne kein Objekt sein, nachvollziehbar untermauert. Auf allen Webseiten, die den Gelichsetzugnsnominativ zum Thema haben, fehlt eine nachvollziehbare Begründung.**

Wie in der Antwort dazu steht, fehlt Namen schlicht die Flektion für die Einordnung in das synthetische Gefüge. Die Kasus-Endung klammert mit dem Verb das Objekt in einer Verbalphrase ein. Von einem Nullmorpheme auszugehen ist nur sinnvoll, wenn doch irgendein Effekt nachweisbar ist, zb. bezüglich der Satzstellung.

Da die Aktionsart in der Gleichsetzung egal ist, hat 1. *Mein Name ist ...* die gleiche Valenz wie 2. *ich heiße ...*. Je nach Diskurs erfordert die umgekehrte Reihenfolge eine unterschiedlicher Betonung. Ohnedies ist der Ausgang häufig nicht markiert.

Es ist im Grunde auch kein Genus oder Numerus gegeben, denn der folgt aus dem Sachverhalt (2) und zwecks der Gleichsetzung (1). Sprich, ein Name als Symbol hat in der Regel keinen Genus. Daher fällt es auch nicht schwer, auf den Kasus zu verzichten.

Es gibt aber einen Klassifikator, *Sie gaben ihm den Namen ...* - dagegen determiniert "Ich bin der Maxwell". Hier könnte man noch fragen, ob *Namensgebung* als feststehender Begriff das Nomen *Namen* dem Prädikat zuordnen lässt, da ohne Substanz ein gewichtiger unterschied zum Substantiv besteht. Gleichermaßen wäre dann (1) schwierig zu bewerten: vgl. *sich einig sein*, *jmds. Name sein*. Da würde mancher (ich hoffe ich bin nicht der einzige) eventuel zur Flektion tendieren,

> ? er behauptet, sein Namen wäre Maxwell

nicht nur, weil das fast nach *agreement* klingt, sondern weil der Name an das Hauptverb im Matrixsatz gebunden wird, was zufällig auch ohne Umschweife möglich ist, *er behauptet den Namen Maxwell*. Ob der Ausfall des n, das in *Nomen* noch zu sehen ist, auf Faulheit zurückzuführen ist, pg. *namô < pie. *h₁nómn̥, der ob es sonst als Nullmorphem in *Nam'* untergeht, vgl. *bei name nenn'*, mhd. *nemnen, nennen*, laut Duden ist nominativ *Namen* alternativ zulässig.

Das ist dann wirklich relativ ungenau, ach schau, zwei kaum miteinander verwandte Wörter, reiner Zufall. Anders lies sich das vermutlich nicht lösen. Andernfalls müsste für jede Verbalphrasa ein Wörterbucheintrag konstruiert werden und überprüft werden. Un Lehrbüchern stebt der Satz jedoch. Das berührt die Grammatik kaum (1). Das wäre dann schlicht Verb und Subjekt als Praedikat; sagt so aber keiner. Vielleicht weicht es die Bedeutung des Begriffs hinreichend auf.

Praedikate sind in der Aussagenlogik eigentlich Beziehungen mit bijektiven Maps, *Alice ist Bob sein Vater* P(A|B), *Bob ist niemandem Vater* P(B|_), also ist das auch sprachlich nicht sehr genau. *Bob ist Doktor* D(B) ist wiederum nicht immer eine Gleichsetzung, sondern Gruppenzugehörigkeit. Dafür gäbe es auch das passende Prädikat E(B|D). Vorallem ist *das Bob* B(x) selbst ein Praedikat und das Problem sind die Pronomina: *eine Rose ist eine Rose*...

Auch auf Diskursebene ist der Name im Fokus. Nur bei *ich* fällt das quasi zusammen, wenn sich jemand mit *ich* identifiziert. Andernfalls:  *(Da / das hier) ist der Mann, den Sie... * ist relativ unabhängig vom Vollverb, weil der Fall vorallem dem Objekt folgt. Im einfachsten Fall wäre

> ? Da! (Den / Der) in Orange!"

mit Hilfe Gebärden genauso verständlich*.

Das Hilfsverb *ist* kann nicht nur polysem sondern auch polyvalent sein und mehrere Prädikate aufnehmen, *Das ist, wonach Sie gesucht haben, wer oder was Ihnen fehlt, das ich Ihnen sowieso schon Mal zeigen wollte.* Das Praedikat wird immer komplexer. Den Satz könnte man zwar als Ellipse aus *ist es* konstruieren, *das is' es, is's, iss*, tatsächlich öfter mit langem Konsonant. Jedenfalls ist das Komma, bzw. das Pronomen und dessen klitische Bindung an das Prädikat durchaus bemerkenswert. Außerdem kann man "Das isses!" nur als Verbalphrase auffassen.

> **Wie genau ist der Begriff "Prädikat" in der deutschen Grammatik definiert?**

Die Frage lautete zwar etwas anders im Titel. "genau" und präzise ist die Definition des Prädikats nicht.

So sehen es auch Althaus/Henne/Wiegand in Lexikon der Germanistischen Linguistik (1980, degruyter),

p. 213, § 19.2.3 Satzstruktur (*"Historische" Syntax*)

> 2.3.1 In der historischen Syntax wird der zweigliedrige Satz, bestehend aus Subjekt und Prädikat, als Prototyp („Urform des Satzes") angesehen (H. Paul51920, 282). Aus dem Verhältnis von
> Subjekt und Prädikat entspringen die übrigen syntaktischen Verhältnisse. [...]

p. 213, § 19.3.1 Theoretisches Konzept (*"traditionelle" Syntax*)

> Gemeinsames Prinzip ist die polydimensionale
> Betrachtungsweise der grammatischen Erscheinungen (W. Admoni 1973, 61: „nicht formalisierte offene Grammatiktheorien"). Ein einheitliches Bestimmungs- und Klassifizierungsverfahren wird nicht angestrebt; [...]

p. 214, § 19.3.5 Satzbaupläne

> Den Kernbereich der „traditionellen" Syntax bildet ein Inventar von Satztypen, die als Muster für die Bildung von Satzformen im Kommunikationsprozeß angesehen werden. Die Angaben weichen stark voneinander ab: Duden-Grammatik, 1959: 17 „Grundformen mit Untertypen"; H. Glinz, 1957: 9 „geistige Grundbilder"; H. Brinkmann
> 1962: 4 „Satzmodelle"; W. Admoni 31970: 12 „logisch-grammatische Satztypen".

Zumindest bis in die 80er hinein war das also alles andere als genau bestimmt, was mithin das bestreben nach generativer bzw. funktionaler Grammatik begründet. Bekannter Maßen scheiden sich die Geister bis heute daran.

> **Gehört ein Wort, das weder zum Subjekt noch zum Prädikat gehört, immer automatisch zu einem Objekt?**

Ja, vermutlich. Da die Betonung eine entscheidende Rolle spielt, genügt es in den vereinfachten Beispielen (1, 2) von SVO auszugehen und den Rest pragmatisch zu handhaben. S. Althaus et al. s. pp. 9-10, § 1.2.2.2 Prädikation (1. *Sprachphilosophie*)

> Die hier klar erkennbare Unentschiedenheit Freges [...] muß als Ursprung der noch heute herrschenden Unklarheiten bei der Diskussion um den propositionalen Gehalt eines Satzes gelten, [...]

Comment: Und wo genau steht nun die Antwort auf meine Frage?

Comment: Die Antowrt steht am Schluss, dass es keine genaue Definition gibt. Die bereits gegebene Definition (von äöü, oben) habe ich so gesehen nicht bestritten, aber abgewertet, weshalb ich mich zu einer eigenen Antwort gezwungen sah, obwohl mich an der Antowort nur der erste Satz gestört hatte.